# Having issues returning 4 columns by joining 3 tables and using aliases in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, join

I am still very new at `SQL` and was unable to find an answer on here...I am supposed to write a `SELECT` statement that `returns 4 columns from 3 tables` using `aliases` and then assign correlation names to the tables... But I am getting an `error` on the `WHERE` clause and I am not quite sure how to `join` the 3 tables to get the results I am looking for. Also, it did not specify which type of `JOIN` to do.

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT VendorName AS [Vendor], InvoiceDate AS [Date], InvoiceNumber AS [Number], AccountItemDescription AS [Description]
    FROM Vendors AS v JOIN Invoices AS i 
    ON v.VendorID = i.InvoiceID
    JOIN InvoiceLineItems AS l JOIN GLAccounts AS g 
    WHERE l.InvoiceLineItems = g.GLAccounts
    ORDER BY Vendor, Description;-- Unfinished
```

Getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Any tips would be GREATLY appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It helps to be careful in how you format your code. Every `join` should have an `on` clause. You are missing them on your `InvoiceLineItems` and `GLAccounts` joins.

Additionally, your `on` clause will typically link the primary key of one table to the foreign key in another; joining `Vendors` to `Invoices` by equating `vendorID` to `invoiceID` is not going to give you accurate results. Those IDs have no direct correlation. You want to link `vendorID` from one table to the `vendorID` in the other. I'm not sure how your fields are named; it could be `i.vendorID = v.vendorID` or it could be something like `i.vendorID = v.id.` Follow the same pattern for your other joins.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
SELECT VendorName AS [Vendor], 
    InvoiceDate AS [Date], 
    InvoiceNumber AS [Number],
    AccountItemDescription AS [Description]
FROM Vendors AS v 
JOIN Invoices AS i ON i.VendorID = v.VendorID
JOIN InvoiceLineItems AS l ON l.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
JOIN GLAccounts AS g ON l.GLAccountID = g.GLAccountID
ORDER BY Vendor, Description;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
 SELECT VendorName AS [Vendor], InvoiceDate AS [Date], 
        InvoiceNumber AS [Number],   AccountItemDescription AS [Description]
FROM Vendors AS v 
       JOIN Invoices AS i ON v.VendorID = i.InvoiceID
       JOIN InvoiceLineItems AS l  --YOU MISS AN ON CLAUSE HERE
       JOIN GLAccounts AS g ON l.InvoiceLineItems = g.GLAccounts
ORDER BY Vendor, Description;
```

You add the joining in an old style leaving the new one without the `ON` clause which was generating the error

Since I don't know your table structure I can't suggest what to put there.

Comment: Hmmm... I added "ON" but it is still giving me and error and says:

'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.'

It makes sense, though.

Comment: Hello downvoter, would you explain why this was downvoted? please